# How to assign an index to different node clusters? (for pathfinding)

Tags: unity, path-finding, grid, rts, navmesh

Hellow~

So for a bit of context: i'm currently working on a RTS (way above may league) which already has a level editor and a node grid which maps the terrain, i previously make a navigation system with A* as explainned by Sebastian Lague in his [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0cq5Umv3pMC9SPnKjfp9eGW) about the topic, but then i run into a problem when running with multiple units (not the point here: but never manage to find each unit cluster within the selection), so i change it into a navmesh mapping which if made dynamic by assigning navmesh obstacles to the unwalkable nodes (the frame after the creation of the node grid)

**Now i want to use the node grid basically to check if the target node and the start node share the same node cluster. But here is the thing: i can't assign the needed index to the nodes as i expected.**

I've been trying adapting code from this [post](https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/number-of-islands-using-bfs/), but didn't quite make it.
Now i have this one, which i think could achieve something but still gets me a invalid operation exception:

```
public const int UNWALKABLE_ISLAND = 999;

public static void SetIslands(ref WorldGrid _worldGrid) {
    int width = _worldGrid.nodeGrid.GetLength(0);
    int height = _worldGrid.nodeGrid.GetLength(1);

    bool[,] visited = new bool[width, height];

    int clusterCount = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            if (visited[x, y]) { continue; } else {
                List<Node> cluster = new List<Node>() {
                    _worldGrid.nodeGrid[x, y]
                };

                foreach (var node in cluster) {
                    if (node.isWalkable)
                    {
                        visited[node.X, node.Y] = true;
                        node.SetIslandIndex(clusterCount);
                        cluster.AddRange(_worldGrid.GetNeighbours8D(node));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cluster.Remove(node);
                    }
                }

                clusterCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException (System.ExceptionResource resource) (at<437ba245d8404787b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare() (at<437ba245d8404787b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext() (at<437ba245d8404787b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> Pathfinding.SetIslands (WorldGrid& _worldGrid) (at Assets/Pathfinding.cs: 25)
> WorldGrid.CreateNodeGrid() (at Assets/WorldGrid:80)
> WorldGrid+d_12.MoveNext() (at Assets/WorldGrid.cs:42)
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, Sustem.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at<437ba245d8404787b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

My node class contains an int that should hold the cluster index, which will be using for the request check. (the code its based from this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/CGMNePwovA0))

Right now i'm trying to understand the spectral clustering stuff, i've been told it could help.

I hope you can help an animator in need with some pointers.

Cheers :3

*Oh!, I also tried reading the nav agent path end coordinate for comparison, but it ended up becoming a huge mess for me.

Comment: What line throws an invalid operation exception? What message comes along with the exception?

Comment: Hi!, the error is the following: https://imghub.io/i/sX9vk, as for the line 25, it corresponds with `foreach (var node in cluster) {`. Line 80 in WorldGrid.cs is the calling of the method `Pathfinding.SetIslands(ref Instance);`

Comment: That belongs in the text of your question, not in an image hosted off-site tucked away in the comments. Since this is a standard exception, is it safe to assume you started by [searching StackOverflow for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foreach+collection+was+modified+enumeration+operation+may+not+execute&searchOn=3) and applying the answers there to your case? I notice for example that `foreach` occurs nowhere in the code you're modifying.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll add the error to the main question for reading, yes i did try that. At some point I had a dictionary<int,List<Node>> to sort all the clusters but it didn't work like i thought. Nevertheless i didn't spend that much time looking out for more examples on exceptions, so will get back at it just in case. Cheers

Comment: What your error basically wants to tell you: don't touch your collection (add/ remove) in the foreach.

Comment: Hello Frame Matt! Welcome to a StackExchange community! Here, when you've fix the issue, we mark the answer as _accepted_ instead of editing the title as "solved". You'll be able to do that in a day or two :) This tells other folks, and the system, that the issue is fixed :)

Comment: @Zibelas Yes, i actually tried to turn that foreach into a while loop, and having the lists started outside of the while scope, but ended up throwing the same error. So at some point i started to look into other solutions that allowed that kind of iteration, and come by a video of Nick White on youtube, which inspired a similar solution for me (check the answer).

Comment: @Vaillancourt Oup!, got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woot!

I manage to set up island indexes by flood filling the nodes, in different manner as i was attempting.
Here is the code for further reference:

```
private static int clusterIndex = 0;
private static bool[,] visited;

public static void FloodIslands()
{
    int width = WorldGrid.Instance.nodeGrid.GetLength(0);
    int height = WorldGrid.Instance.nodeGrid.GetLength(1);
    visited = new bool[width, height];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            if (visited[x, y] || !WorldGrid.Instance.nodeGrid[x,y].isWalkable && !visited[x, y]) { continue; }
            else {
                SearchCluster(x, y, width, height, clusterIndex);
                clusterIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void SearchCluster(int _x, int _y, int _width, int _height, int _desiredIndex) {
    if (_x < 0 || _y < 0 || _x >= _width || _y >= _height || 
        WorldGrid.Instance.nodeGrid[_x, _y].isWalkable == false ||
        WorldGrid.Instance.nodeGrid[_x,_y].IslandIndex == _desiredIndex) {
        return;
    }

    Node node = WorldGrid.Instance.nodeGrid[_x, _y];

    node.SetIslandIndex(_desiredIndex);
    visited[node.X, node.Y] = true;

    SearchCluster(_x + 1, _y, _width, _height, _desiredIndex);
    SearchCluster(_x - 1, _y, _width, _height, _desiredIndex);
    SearchCluster(_x, _y + 1, _width, _height, _desiredIndex);
    SearchCluster(_x, _y - 1, _width, _height, _desiredIndex);
}
```

This way i didn't had to deal with the wierd collection exceptions.

*DMGregory thank you so much for the tip, even though i couldn't make it work around the list, it did push me to look for alternatives, until i hit [this reference](https://youtu.be/aehEcTEPtCs) (a youtube video from Nick White).